# How to dump .data section of PE files?

Tags: linux, windows

So, I was able to disassemble with Linux's `objdump`, and I was able to extract the `.data`, but I was unable to interpret it effectively. Is there a way to dump it in a more readable format, similar to how `objdump` allows us to read the `.text`? I did some googling & played with the help options, I didn't find anything useful.